# Pyspark dataproc job failure

Tags: pyspark, coursera-api

I got below error log while submitting the `pyspark dataproc` job on creating recommendations.

> 18/09/15 06:11:36 
>           INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
>           18/09/15 06:11:36 
>           org.spark_project.jetty.server.Server: Started @3317ms
>           18/09/15 06:11:37 INFO org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: 
>           StartedServerConnector@6322b8bd{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
>           18/09/15 06:11:37 INFO 
>           com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 
>           1.6.8-hadoop218/09/15 06:11:38 
>           INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy:
>           Connecting to ResourceManager at cluster-d21a-m/10.128.0.4:8032
>           18/09/15 06:11:41
>           INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted 
>           application application_1536988234373_0004 18/09/15 06:11:46 
>           WARN org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Spark is not running in local mode, 
>           therefore the checkpoint directory must not be on the local filesystem. 
>           Directory 'checkpoint/' appears to be on the local filesystem.read ...
>           Traceback (most recent call last):File "/tmp/job-
>           614e830d/train_and_apply.py", line 50, in 
>           model = ALS.train(dfRates.rdd, 20, 20) # you could tune these numbers,
>           but these are reasonable choices     File 
>           "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py",
>           line 272, in train
>           File 
>           "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py", 
>            line 229, 
>            in_prepareFile "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", 
>            line 1364, in firstValueError:RDD is empty/09/15 06:11:53 INFO 
>            org.spark_project.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: 
>            Stopped Spark@6322b8bd{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}`

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Please provide additional information like what is the code, what environment you are using.

Comment: Iam taking training on GCP  from coursera . This code is part of  a lab session to create Recommendations Machine Learning Algorithm with pySpark.  train_and_apply.py is the ml model  which is stored in  cloud storage bucket. and i submitted a dataproc job to execute the code.